# How to Set A Condition (if-else) Based on a SQL within a MACRO

Tags: sql, if-statement, macros, jinja2, dbt

I've created a custom macro that creates a local database and its schemas at Snowflake. However, in my macro I placed an `if` condition that will check if the same named database has already been created. If it is already generated, the `else` statement should be involved and bypass all Database Creation Scripts and just complete Schema Creation scripts(after for loop). But 'else' statement is not working and it's giving the Compilation Error saying that database already exists.

```
{% macro create_local_database(username, reset_environment = false) %}

  {%- set current_dbt_schemas = ["MART", "MART_ADVANCED"] %}

  {% set setup_database_name_check %}
      SELECT DISTINCT DATABASE_NAME
      FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATABASES
      WHERE DATABASE_NAME  =  'ANALYTICS_LOCAL_MART_{{username}}'
  {% endset %}
  {% set existing_database = run_query(setup_database_name_check).columns[0][0] %}

{% if existing_database != 'ANALYTICS_LOCAL_MART_{{username}}' %}
{% set setup_database_script %}
    {%- if reset_environment == false -%}
      {% do log('Creating Database', True) %}
      CREATE DATABASE ANALYTICS_LOCAL_MART_{{username}}

    {%- elif reset_environment == true -%}
      {{ log(this ~ "Operation Completed : " ~ run_started_at.astimezone(modules.pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")), true) }}
      CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE ANALYTICS_LOCAL_MART_{{username}}
      {% do log('Replaced Database', True) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endset %}
{% do run_query(setup_database_script) %}


{% for schema in current_dbt_schemas %}
    {{schema}}
    {% set setup_schema_script1 %}
        CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {{schema}} WITH MANAGED ACCESS
        {{ log(this ~ " Creating Schema (" ~ schema ~ ")" ~ msg, true) }}
    {% endset %}
    {% do run_query(setup_schema_script1) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ log(this ~ "Operation Completed : " ~ run_started_at.astimezone(modules.pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")), true) }}


{# the below script is not working#}

{% else %}  
{% for schema in current_dbt_schemas %}
    {{schema}}
    {% set setup_schema_script1 %}
        CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {{schema}} WITH MANAGED ACCESS
        {{ log(this ~ " Creating Schema (" ~ schema ~ ")" ~ msg, true) }}
    {% endset %}
    {% do run_query(setup_schema_script1) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ log(this ~ "Operation Completed : " ~ run_started_at.astimezone(modules.pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")), true) }}

{% endif %}


{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is caused by dbt's two-pass architecture, where it has to execute your macro's code in order to compile your project. See [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/execute).

The first time dbt parses this code, `run_query` is gated by `if execute`, so `existing_databases` will be `None`. This will cause dbt to execute the first branch of your if statement.

You can fix this by wrapping your whole macro in an `{% if execute %}` block:

```sql
{% macro create_local_database(username, reset_environment = false) %}
{% if execute %}
...
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```